# Looping through sheets looking at index using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, loops, worksheet, xlsxwriter

I am wondering is their anyway I can iterate over a worksheet and determine len of my index using xlsxwriter? The code that I am using right now isnt working how I want.

```
for worksheet in workbook.worksheets():
    if len(worksheet.index) <= 1:
       worksheet.hide()
    else:
        move on and do something else
```

what I am expecting it to do is look and see if their is more than 1 row of data and if their is continue else hide that worksheet. once again I am using xlsxwriter and I havent found a way to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public method to determine is a XlsxWriter worksheet has data since the parent application can track this itself when it adds data.

As an alternative you could check that the `worksheet.dim_rowmax` is not `None`.

P.S. it is a little odd that the application is adding empty worksheets and then hiding them. This may be confusing to the end user. Maybe you can figure out if you need to add data first before creating empty worksheets.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I will definitely look into it